# How do I implement HierarchyId in EF Core 6 in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, hierarchyid

I am developing a simple project management system and needed to manage the WBS (basicly a hierarchy of tasks).  I spent several days combing through blog after blog after blog to figure out how to setup the `HierarchyId` using EF Core and SQL Server.  I ran into a lot of errors about the type not being supported by the Db and converting to a CLR type (i think it was).  Which drove me to try and do mapping in my database context file, none of which worked.

So I wanted to share a summary of what ended up working with the hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

When you read blogs on implementing `HierarchyId`, you have to be very conscious of EF 6 vs EF Core 6.  Some blogs articles will not be specify and the two and the solutions are not the same.  I think some of my problem was MY inexperience and so I had pieces of a solution from EF and some from EF Core.

I am working on .Net 6, EF Core 6, and Sql Server (latest version).

You should already have

```
     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

The only additional package you need is `EntityFramworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId`.  The current version is 3.0.1.

In Program.cs add `UseHierarchyId()` to your UseSqlServer like this:

```
    builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<DatabaseContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.UseHierarchyId()));
```

When you create your database model add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`  Here is an example of my model, you will see the `HierarchyId` at the bottom.

```
    public class TaskModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EstimatedStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EstimatedEndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ActualStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ActualEndDate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TaskStatusModel> TaskStatus { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TaskTimeModel> TaskTime { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TaskResourceModel> TaskResource { get; set; }
        public HierarchyId Level { get; set; }
    }
```

When you run `Add-Migration  Update-Database` it will create the table with the HierarchyId type as expected.

One odd behavior (or bug) I've noticed is the HierarchyId will have an error before or during a build.  You'll also see that the `EntityFramworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId` package is missing from the list in VS.  From reading, it may be a compatibility problem. I don't know.

[image]

I find that you just rebuild again and it will resolve itself.  This tends to happen alternately with successful builds.  I've not found a solution to this yet.